# Getting errors when installing Compass

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, sass, compass

I'm running Ubuntu with ruby:

```
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

got Sass 3.4.9 installed and now I'm trying to install Compass from `http://compass-style.org/install/` but when running gem install compass am getting errors:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing compass:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /usr/bin

/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.6/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
```

this is the log file content:

```
  /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

I've been googling for hours and am still stuck. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a issue.
You can see more info here:
https://github.com/sass/sass/pull/1527 > https://github.com/guard/listen/issues/275